# Media Queries not working on iOS, but working on android

Tags: html, css, ios, responsive-design, media-queries

I use media queries to make my website responsive on mobile devices. When resizing the window in google chromes mobile view or when i open the website on android devices everything looks as expected. However, when opening the website on Safari/Chrome on an iOS device, elements are misplaced and the font is also the default font and not my specified font.

I tried to adapt the viewport but that did not change anything. I read that iOS has problems recognizing the viewport, is that true? If yes, can anyone help fixing that, since i haven't found a working solution online. Many thanks in advance!
This is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    ...
  </head>
```

and the media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover; /* Ensure the background covers the entire body */
    padding: 10px; /* Adjust padding for better spacing on small screens */
  }

  .wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  p {
    padding: 0; /* Remove padding for paragraphs on small screens */
  }

  p:tiny,
  p:medium {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  #tag-container,
  .tag {
    margin: 5px 2px; /* Adjust margins for tags on small screens */
  }

  .modal-container {
    padding: 10px; /* Adjust padding for modals on small screens */
  }

  .card {
    max-width: 100%; /* Make sure cards take up full width on small screens */
  }
}
```